# Returning parameterized List from Scala function

Tags: list, scala, parameterized

I am getting error in the following code:

```
def times(chars: List[Char]): List[Int] = {
    List(1)
}
```

The error says the following:

> type mismatch;  found   : scala.collection.immutable.scala.collection.immutable.List[Int] 
>   required: < empty >.List[Int]

Any idea why this error?

Comment: Have you got another definition of `List` elsewhere in the file? The `List` in `List[Char]` and `List[Int]` is a (parameterised) type, but `List(1)` is a call to the `List` object's apply method... so you could have your own `List` type but still be calling the default `List` object's apply.

Answer (score 0):

try

> chars(1)

if i'm right you trying to return nothing, not your list

Comment: You are wrong. `chars(1)` is a `Char`, not a `List[Int]`.